# Create a folder with SQL 2018

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a folder in the file explorer from within SQL Server Management Studio 18. Is this even possible? I know with VBA you can do it. I tried some code I found online, I even enabled `xp_cmdshell` and it runs but no folder is created. I tried with this code but pretty sure I'm missing something.

```
declare @cmdpath nvarchar(60)
set @cmdpath = 'MD '+ @Location
exec master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @cmdpath
```

or this one:

```
declare @FilePath varchar(100)
set @FilePath = 'D:\FolderTest'
EXEC master.dbo.xp_create_subdir @FilePath
```

Comment: This is a bad idea. I suggest you explain the larger picture so we can suggest an alternative. With regards to your actual, problem, what do you see in the output screen in management studio? What happens if you inspect with `xp_cmdshell 'DIR D:\'`. Note that this ocurring on the _server_, not the _client_.

Comment: So you didn't like the comments from your same question on [msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/eefbbe20-5dc3-4939-b592-c2d3e51e1bbc/create-folder-with-sql?forum=sqltools). But they still apply - tsql has no built in functionality to manipulate the file system and doing so requires certain permissions. You are using the wrong tool / approach.

Answer (score 0):

SQL is a means of relating to a database. Typically queries are embedded in another file (a python script or java application for example). The job of creating files and folders falls outside the database and would not be handled by a query.

**So the short answer is no. SQL is not the thing to use to make files and folders.**

Comment: Not an answer. Should be a comment.

Comment: Question: `Is this even possible?` Answer: `Yes in some flavors of SQL but not advisable.`

Comment: It's advisable under some circumstances and not under other circumstances.

Comment: In what circumstance would you advise this?

Comment: Infrequently is my advice.